# How to pass arguments to PDO SELECT statement in an array in a 'reusable' way?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm new to PDO and have successfully converted most of my site's inserts and updates to PDO transactions, each in a centrally accessible function for maximum reuse. I really want to do the same with the `SELECT` statements, but this seems harder!

What I was expecting to do is this:

```
function getProdDetails2SaveInInvoice($data) {

    global $dbh;

    try {
        $sth=$dbh->prepare("
        SELECT
            AES_DECRYPT(?, '".DBKEY,"'),
            AES_DECRYPT(?, '".DBKEY,"'),
            AES_DECRYPT(?, '".DBKEY,"')
         FROM
            products
        WHERE
            ? ? ?
    ");

        $sth->execute($data);
        $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        return $sth;
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo  "Something went wrong. Please report this error.\n";
        file_put_contents(
            $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/PDOErrors.txt",
            "\n\nScript name : ".SCRIPT."\nFunction name : ".__FUNCTION__."\n".
            $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);

        throw new failedTransaction();
    }
}

// Fetch additional info from invoice_products.
        $data = array(
            'alt_id',           /* field 1                  */
            'prod_name',        /* field 2                  */
            'prod_desc',        /* field 3                  */
            'prod_id',          /* where                    */
            '=',                /* operator                 */
            $prodid         /* comparison               */
        );
        $rs = getProdDetails2SaveInInvoice($data);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and returns the error,

> ERROR:"Call to a member function execute() on a non-object".

I can confirm that the `$dbh` database connection is working as it's the same connection working for the inserts and updates.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if you can't put it in single-quotes in a "classic" query you can't bind it either. Your query would look like `SELECT .... WHERE 'prod_id' '=' '1234'` and only the '1234' fragment is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind the field names. Assuming DBKEY is a constant, your query should look like this:

```
$sth=$dbh->prepare("
        SELECT
            AES_DECRYPT(alt_id, ?),
            AES_DECRYPT(prod_name, ?),
            AES_DECRYPT(prod_desc, ?)
         FROM
            products
        WHERE
            prod_id = ?
    ");
```

and $data like this:

```
$data = array(
            DBKEY, 
            DBKEY, 
            DBKEY,
            $prodid
        );
```

Comment: That did it. Not as compact or re-usable as I would have liked but I think it's as good as it gets! Many thanks.

Comment: yeah... if you'd like to also have flexibility in regards to the fields names, you could pass in another another array with the fields and just concatenate the field names. you should be watching out for sql injection though if you're receiving the field names from external sources.

Comment: Good point @Alexandru Mihai, (the fields are not supplied externally ever). Might give the other array with the fields in a try in a day or two after I've got the basics working.

Comment: As a follow-on to my question... I still haven't successfully accessed a result! Looks like I have to ask another question about that though since I can't really go into details here without formatting available.

Comment: You can Edit your Question if the edit is relevant to the original.